# Got many error from "sklearn" Python library

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I run simple code in `jupyter`:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
```

and I didn't use `numpy` library but I got this:

```
g:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\image.py:167: DeprecationWarning: `np.int` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `int`. To silence this warning, use `int` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. When replacing `np.int`, you may wish to use e.g. `np.int64` or `np.int32` to specify the precision. If you wish to review your current use, check the release note link for additional information.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  dtype=np.int):
g:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\base.py:240: DeprecationWarning: `np.int` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `int`. To silence this warning, use `int` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. When replacing `np.int`, you may wish to use e.g. `np.int64` or `np.int32` to specify the precision. If you wish to review your current use, check the release note link for additional information.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  target = np.empty((n_samples,), dtype=np.int)
g:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\base.py:244: DeprecationWarning: `np.int` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `int`. To silence this warning, use `int` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. When replacing `np.int`, you may wish to use e.g. `np.int64` or `np.int32` to specify the precision. If you wish to review your current use, check the release note link for additional information.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  target[i] = np.asarray(ir[-1], dtype=np.int)
```

Comment: It's not an errors, it's just warnings about some deprecated `sklearn` features

Comment: You should perform a `pip install -U scikit-learn numpy` as it seems that you are using old packages versions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your libraries are outdated, hence this deprecation warning.

I would advise you to update `numpy` and `scikit-learn` using the following command:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn numpy
```